# Overriding map in a class that extends Array in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

Say just for fun I want to override `Array` and redefine `map`:

```
public dynamic class MagicArray extends Array {
  public override function map(f:Function, thisObject:* = null):Array {
    var result:Array = [];

    for (var i:int = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      result.push(f(this[i]));
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

We get this error: `Method marked override must override another method.`

Huh?

So I stripped the `override` keyword and tried again. Now, everything compiles fine. But if we try to use it:

```
var a:MagicArray = new MagicArray([1,2,3]);
a.map(function(x) { return x + 1; });
```

We get the following error:

`Error: Ambiguous reference to map.`

So what's going on here? How can I override `map`?

Comment: Interesting idea of fun, maybe consider a hobby  :-), really though not sure I'll see if I can dig up anything about map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make the extension dynamic and are you using the namespace see here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8d829-7fde.html

Comment: Yeah that's the one. Darn, I had seen that link before but forgot all about that crazy `AS3 override` stuff. Thanks!